# Is it possible to stop OpenAPI Maven plugin from creating models?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Is there a way to avoid the plugin generating the models for us? The problem is that I need to create my own model and I do not want to use the generate one.

I saw that there is only a way to tell the plugin to use our class for model but I did not see a way to block at all the model generation

Comment: `<generateModels>false</generateModels>` in the configuration of the plugin ? according to the plugin doc: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Comment: Thanks, works , now the issue is that obviously the api cannot find models. I need a way to use the generated models but I need to add them annotations etc, how can I do?

Comment: Read the doc, man :)

Comment: I do not think I can find in docs this thinks. Like I need to add to generated models some Hibernate annotation, how can I do?

Comment: How do you know it's not in the doc if you don't read it ? I never used this plugin, I found the answer for your question by reading the doc for 3 minutes. Really, you should read it.

Comment: do you have the url?

Comment: I gave it to you in my first comment but you can use google also :)

Comment: though `<generateModels>false</generateModels>` still generates the abstract class `AbstractOpenApiSchema` which is unwanted.